# Parts of my code work on it's on, but not in a method.

Tags: python, sorting, radix

I'm trying to implement my own version of a radix sort. The large section at the bottom of the program that I have commented out works as intended with no errors, however, when I place it into a method call main_sort, I get an error: 'Nontype' object is not iteratable. It's literally the same code, copy and pasted and I cannot see what I have done wrong. I have indicated the line where the error occurs, but as I said I don't know why I'm getting one.

```
def read_file(file):
    with open(file) as f:
        content = [x.strip('\n') for x in f.readlines()]
    f.close()
    return content

def create_bins(list):
    if list == listDec:
        sortBins = {item : [] for item in dictionIndexes[:10]}
        return sortBins
    elif list == listOct:
        sortBins = {item : [] for item in dictionIndexes[:8]}
        return sortBins
    elif list == listHex:
        sortBins = {item : [] for item in dictionIndexes}
        return sortBins

def sort(list, index):
    bins = create_bins(list)
    for key in bins: //WHERE THE ERROR OCCURS
        for num in list:
            if num[index] == key:
                bins[key].append(num)
    return bins

def main_sort(list):
    mainBin = []
    index = -1
    while index > -11:
        sortBins = sort(list, index)
        for key in sorted(sortBins):
            for items in sortBins[key]:
                mainBin.append(items)
        if index == -10:
            break
        else:
            list = mainBin
            mainBin = []
            index = index - 1
    return list

# mainBin = []
dictionIndexes = "0123456789ABCDEF"
sortBins = {}
#Number lists
listDec = read_file("Number Lists/random_numbers10.txt")
listHex = read_file("Number Lists/random_numbers4.txt")
listOct = read_file("Number Lists/random_numbers3.txt")
# outputFile = open("output.txt", "w")

#The main sort part, just need to change between listHex, Oct and Dec
# index = -1
# while index > -11:
#     sortBins = sort(listHex, index)
#     for key in sorted(sortBins):
#         for items in sortBins[key]:
#             mainBin.append(items)
#     if index == -10:
#         break
#     else:
#         listHex = mainBin
#         mainBin = []
#         index = index - 1

# for item in mainBin:
#     outputFile.write(item + "\n")

var = main_sort(listDec)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that, inside `main_sort`, you do `list=mainBin`, so `list` will point to something else than, let's say, `ListDec`, after an iteration.

I added a few prints so you can understand where is the issue:

```
def create_bins(list):
    if list == listDec:
        print("ListDec")
        sortBins = {item : [] for item in dictionIndexes[:10]}
        return sortBins
    elif list == listOct:
        sortBins = {item : [] for item in dictionIndexes[:8]}
        return sortBins
    elif list == listHex:
        sortBins = {item : [] for item in dictionIndexes}
        return sortBins
    else:
        print("not in the list ...")

def sort(list, index):
    print(list)
    bins = create_bins(list)
    print(bins)
    for key in bins: #WHERE THE ERROR OCCURS
        for num in list:
            if num[index] == key:
                bins[key].append(num)
    return bins

def main_sort(list):
    mainBin = []
    index = -1
    while index > -11:
        sortBins = sort(list, index)
        for key in sorted(sortBins):
            for items in sortBins[key]:
                mainBin.append(items)
        if index == -10:
            break
        else:
            list = mainBin
            mainBin = []
            index = index - 1
    return list
```

Result:

```
# first iteration
['22', '12', '472', '224', '15653', '545']
ListDec
{'3': [], '4': [], '5': [], '9': [], '0': [], '2': [], '7': [], '1': [], '8': [], '6': []}
# second iteration ... List != ListDec
['22', '12', '472', '15653', '224', '545']
not in the list ...
None
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sort.py", line 73, in <module>
    var = main_sort(listDec)
  File "sort.py", line 35, in main_sort
    sortBins = sort(list, index)
  File "sort.py", line 25, in sort
    for key in bins: #WHERE THE ERROR OCCURS
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

What to do?

I would advise reworking the `create_bins` function so it does not check the type of data (Dec/Hex/Oct) by testing the equality of the current list